# Вывод элементов ассоциативного массива не содержащих значение

Tags: php, joomla

Добрый день всем!

Есть код:

```
if (count($temp)){
    foreach ($temp as $row){
        if ($row->cat_state == 1){
            $row->route = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row->slug, $row->catslug));
            $related[] = $row;                   
        }
    }
}
```

В ассоциативном массиве `$row->catslug` есть значение `uncategorised`. Как сделать вывод всех элементов массива не содержащих значение `uncategorised`?

Answer (score 0):

Просто отфильтровать функцией [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

```
if (count($temp)){
    foreach ($temp as $row){
        if ($row->cat_state == 1){
            $catslug = array_filter(
                $row->catslug,
                function($catSlugRow) {
                    return $catSlugRow != 'uncategorised';
                }
            );
            $row->route = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row->slug, $row->catslug));
            $related[] = $row;                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверил, фильтрация не работает, в массив  $row->catslug попадает uncategorised.

Comment: Как изменить эту строку   $row->route = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row->slug, $row->catslug)), чтобы в массив $row->catslug не попадала uncategorised????

Comment: Функция array_filter не меняет исходный массив, а возвращает изменённый, его и нужно использовать, как я показал в примере.
Если всё равно не работает, то пришлите данные, из которых нужно отфильтровать

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понятно вы хотите внести изменения в `Joomla Route`, самый простой метод для удаления `uncategorised` (не включения в  `$row->route`) например:

```
if (count($temp)){
    foreach ($temp as $row){
        if ($row->cat_state == 1){

if($row->catslug == 'uncategorised'){
continue;
}


 $row->route = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row->slug, $row->catslug));
            $related[] = $row;                   
        }
    }
}
```